# how to load different css files with different screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to load *abc.css* file when the screen `width = 1360px` and *xyz.css* load whenthe screen `width = 1600px`. How can i do this with javascript?

Comment: why not just use @media queries?

Comment: why do you want to do this as there are quite a variety of screen sizes? How about the browser not having the full screen?

Comment: i don't have knowledge about media query that's why i have to use these kind of thing

Comment: @Harshana - Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@import url("abc.css") (width: 1360px);
@import url("xyz.css") (width: 1600px);
```

[`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) supports [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/assz3/

Comment: when i use ur answer, my both css file should link to the html page ?

Comment: @Harshana - You should provide both links to `@import` but only the one that satisfies the media query will be applied to your document.

Comment: can i use condition like width <500 then import abc.css ?

Comment: @Harshana - Yes you sure can! But not with the `<` symbol.

Comment: thanks. But not working with my page? is that should be like this?
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/style_1360x760.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/style_1600x900.css">
 <style>
  @import url("Style/style_1360x760.css") (width: 1360px);
  @import url("Style/style_1600x900.css") (width: 1600px);
 </style>`

Comment: @Harshana - You don't need any `<link>` tag since `@import` already take care of it for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48428/discussion-between-harshana-and-derek-)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply specify your width in your link tag i.e:-

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```

this stylesheet will only take affect when the current browser window is between 701 and 900 pixels in width.

Answer (score -1):

From css-tricks

### Using javascript/jQuery

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="narrow.css" />
```

**jQuery**

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/narrow.css");
    } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/medium.css");
    } else {
       $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/wide.css"); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

### Using Media

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="800.css" />
```

#### [Read More ( CSS-Tricks )](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)